# Как найти файл по вхождению в название в Debian?

Tags: debian, find

Нужно найти файл, в имени которого имеется подстрока "IT-технику".
Поиск по

```
find . -name *IT-технику* -print
```

или

```
find . -name "*IT-технику*" -print
```

или

```
find . -name %IT-технику% -print
```

результатов не дает, хотя файл есть точно.

Comment: Быть может, вы с регистром не угадали? Может, `-iname` вместо `-name`?

Comment: Или, может, в имени файла на самом деле дефиса нет и вместо него пробел?

Comment: `find -iname "*IT-технику*"` должен работать. или нет такого файла. скопируйте название файла с консоли, например, и сличите с маской. PS. Могут быть проблемы на самба-шарах. Это ведь не самба?